# SMPP connection using TLV

Tags: java, sms, smpp, tlv, opensmpp

I would like to send commands to the device using Open Smpp protocol.
    API people provided me ProgramID, but i didn't find any method which is accepting programId in open smpp api.

```
So i thought to add it in setExtraOptional(TLV tlv)
but i am not able to set TLV parameter.
I have below values, 

tag = 0x1234, 
programId = 12345

How can i build the TLV from above values?
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is no one there to solve this problem?

Comment: You can simple add request.setExtraOptional((short) 0x1400, new ByteBuffer("programId:12345,String,5".getBytes())); as an extraParameter to Send SM request

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add request.setExtraOptional((short) 0x1400, new ByteBuffer("programId:12345,String,5".getBytes())); as an extraParameter to Send SM request